# separating names

Tags: vb.net, parsing, csv

Im trying to Separate Last name, First Name and Middle Initial. 
File is csv format, here is an example:

```
A0001,3,Y,13,LU,
A0001,3,Y,13,CLARK P,
A0001,3,Y,13,SMITH JOHN,
A0001,3,Y,13,BEAL KRISS J,
A0001,3,Y,13,THOMAS A CLIFF C,
A0001,3,Y,13,DEW III ROBERT H,

Output fields : 
                Last name               First name           Initial   
                  LU                    
                  CLARK                   P 
                  SMITH                   JOHN 
                  BEAL                    KRISS                J 
                  THOMAS A                CLIFF                C 
                  DEW III                 ROBERT               H
```

I hope someone can help with VB script maybe?
 Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1) format your input 2) post the code that you have already tried (format it also)

Comment: The fact that the names are in a CSV file doesn't appear to be truly related to the question. The function that would parse these names shouldn't care that the names came from a field in a csv file.

Comment: @Dennis - sure they would, since csv means comma separated values - this is central to her problem

Comment: @KevinDTimm: I think Dennis's point is that it appears none of the names themselves contain commas. So the true challenge is going from, e.g., "THOMAS A CLIFF C" to `{ FirstName = "CLIFF", LastName = "THOMAS A", Initial = "C" }` -- not splitting the CSV (which looks straightforward in this case).

Comment: @Lenora Welcome to StackOverflow! As Kevin mentioned, you'll get better answers here if you post some code that you've already tried. Do you anticipate having any names that contain 2 middle initials? Will there ever be complete middle names or only initials? Are these that you've listed the only formats that will be valid input?

Comment: @Dennis and Dan - mea culpa - you're correct, the lack of separation will make csv less useful

Answer (score 1):

- First split on coma and get the name
  part seperated.
- Now on the name part, split using
  space and take
- the last element as last name
- second last element as middle name
- and the rest as first name.

Hope this helps,
Happy Programming...

Comment: This is good, but it looks like the first element is the last name instead of the last element.

Comment: Oh, and it might be the first 2 elements as the last name. It is a tricky problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Split()` on each line.  That will give you an array, split on a delimiter... in this case, a comma.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x627e5f(VS.80).aspx